# Shannon-Hartley theorem for multiple channels

Tags: information-theory

The Shannon-Hartley theorem gives an upper bound for the channel capacity $C$ of a single transmission channel as

$$C = B \log_2 (1 + S/N),$$

where $B$ is bandwidth and $S/N$ is the signal to noise ratio.

Is there a generalization for this theorem for multiple (correlated) channels? It seems that correlations between channel signals would reduce the total amount of information, while correlations in noise across channels would increase it. However I haven't found a mathematical framework for dealing with this case.

Comment: Two correlated channels result in a lower entropy since you would not be able to receive independent information bits over each channel; when one channel is weak that's the case for the others as well. On the other hand, if the additive noise among the channels are correlated, it is possible to reduce the noise from other channels given we know the noise in a certain channel and therefore, the capacity improves. This can be mathematically shown as well.

Comment: look for works on the capacity of the MIMO channel